# spark.sql - joining multiple DataFrames. Is it possible?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, join

I am working on the famous yelp dataset with the Business, User and Review data.

My objective for the code is to find the businesses that have been reviewed by more than 5 users that has more than 1000 reviews each.

```
def findFamousBusinessesSQL() : DataFrame = {
    val joined = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM yelpReviewsView yr" +
      "FULL JOIN yelpUsersView yu ON yu.user_id = yr.user_id WHERE review_count > 1000" +            //Join all users based on user_id with a review count of over 1000 reviews
      "INNER JOIN yelpBusinessesView  yb ON yb.business_id = yr.business_id WHERE review_count > 5") // Join everything on business_id, only for businesses with over 5 reviews.


    spark.sql("SELECT name FROM joined ORDER BY review_count DESC") // here I get all the names from the joined variable, and order desc. by review_count.
  }
```

The output should be the names of the businesses in a descending order based on review_count.

This is what 1 user from the  User data looks like:

```
{"user_id":"l6BmjZMeQD3rDxWUbiAiow","name":"Rashmi","review_count":95,"yelping_since":"2013-10-08 23:11:33","useful":84,"funny":17,"cool":25,"elite":"2015,2016,2017","friends":"c78V-rj8NQcQjOI8KP3UEA, alRMgPcngYSCJ5naFRBz5g}
```

Here's date for 1 business:

```
{"business_id":"1SWheh84yJXfytovILXOAQ","name":"Arizona Biltmore Golf Club","address":"2818 E Camino Acequia Drive","city":"Phoenix","state":"AZ","postal_code":"85016","latitude":33.5221425,"longitude":-112.0184807,"stars":3.0,"review_count":5,"is_open":0,"attributes":{"GoodForKids":"False"},"categories":"Golf, Active Life","hours":null}
```

And finally here's the data for 1 Review:

```
{"review_id":"Q1sbwvVQXV2734tPgoKj4Q","user_id":"hG7b0MtEbXx5QzbzE6C_VA","business_id":"ujmEBvifdJM6h6RLv4wQIg","stars":1.0,"useful":6,"funny":1,"cool":0}
```

I filtered some unimportant stuff out from the data, such as the reviews, friends of users etc.

The issue is it seems like I cannot join the things I'd like. It is required of me to use spark.sql for this problem.

The error I get in my IntelliJ says:

```
mismatched input 'FULL' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 114)

== SQL ==
SELECT * FROM yelpReviewsView yr INNER JOIN yelpUsersView yu ON yu.user_id = yr.user_id WHERE review_count > 1000 FULL JOIN yelpBusinessesView  yb ON yb.business_id = yr.business_id WHERE review_count > 5
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

Comment: Your sql syntax looks invalid. `join` can't be placed after `where` clause. Try adding spaces.

Comment: According to your comment, if I remove the last line containing the INNER JOIN, it should work?

Comment: just use `and yr.review_count > 1000` instead of `WHERE review_count > 1000`

Comment: Turns out if I call this 
'spark.sql("SELECT * FROM yelpReviewsView OUTER JOIN influencerUsersDFView ON influencerUsersDFView.user_id")'
It understand better, but it doesn't recognise the .user_id column. It is a string, but want's a boolean. Here's the error:
'join condition 'influencerusersdfview."user_id" of type string is not a boolean.;;' How come?